# Using Python 3.4 to Ping a network then report address, dns name, etc.

Tags: python, file, email, dns, ping

I wanted to create a Python program that does several things. Ping all addresses in a predefined network, gather the DNS information, write a file with IP address, DNS name, ping fail or pass, date. Then run and email the resulting file to myself once a week, every Friday. I have created this program and will post my own answer. I am new to Python and was able to get this written with the help from other answers posted on this site. Thanks to all those who contributed answers on this site. Hope the answer I post will help someone else.

Comment: This is not a question

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
#Above statement makes sure you are using version 3.4
#when multiple versions are installed. has to be the 1st line. 
# Import modules 
import subprocess
import socket
import errno
import time
import datetime
import ipaddress
today = datetime.date.today()
# define DNS lookup and error handling
# return none,none,none needed otherwise if no DNS record
# the routine errors out and the program stops
def lookup(addr):
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)
    except socket.herror:
        return None, None, None

# Prompt the user to input a network address
# commented out the prompt for input so it can run unattended
# net_addr = input("Enter a network address in CIDR     
format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")
net_addr = ('192.168.1.0/24')
# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
# removed code due to errors not windows linux
# setup online and offline count variables
offCnt = 0
onCnt = 0
# Open file and or create if it doesn't exist.
# file to be overwritten each time the program is run.
file = open("lab-ip.doc","w")

# For each IP address in the subnet, 
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
# Grab the DNS information for each IP address
# Print to console add counters and write to file.
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '2', str(all_hosts[i])],     
stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    name,alias,addresslist = lookup(str(all_hosts[i]))
    if "Destination Host Unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), " Ping Fail", str(name), today)
        file.write(str(all_hosts[i]) + " Ping Fail - " + str(name) + " "     + str(today) + "\n")
        offCnt = offCnt + 1
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), " Ping Fail", str(name), today)
        file.write(str(all_hosts[i]) + " Ping Fail - " + str(name) + " "     + str(today) + "\n")
        offCnt = offCnt + 1
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), " Ping Pass", str(name), today)
         file.write(str(all_hosts[i]) + " Ping Pass - " + str(name) + " "     + str(today) + "\n")
        onCnt = onCnt + 1
print ("Pass count = ", str(onCnt))
file.write("Pass count = " + str(onCnt))
print ("Fail count = ", str(offCnt))
file.write(" Fail count = " + str(offCnt))
file.close()
# Import yagmail for the actual sending function
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('Gmail-id', 'gmail-pswd')
yag.send('email@email.com', subject = "Lab-ip List",contents =         'lab-ip.doc')
yag.send('email2@email2.com', subject = "Lab-ip List",contents =     'lab-ip.doc')
#end
```